# SQL Deduplication based on two IDs referencing themselves

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a simple issue for which I can't seem to find a solution.

I have the following table :

```
    **ID1**            **ID2**
      123                ABC
      123                DEF
      456                ABC
```

I have two sets IDs per people (ID1 and ID2), and sometimes, people generate more than one of each. I want to deduplicate my rows based on those, as they will always reference to one another somehow.
This example is showing 3 lines for one single person, which has two different set of IDs (result of working with different non-unified systems...).

If I use a count(distinct ID1), 2 will be returned and that would be wrong.

Would you know how to this ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: What exactly are you hoping for in the end?

Comment: Hi! I'm hoping to get the real deduplicated count of users I have in my table.

Comment: And I'm using SQL Server